# Find out what happens in a specific thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, cpu-usage

I'm developing an app that's quite simple, but uses 3% CPU constantly when I present a certain View. I figured out that this happens in a unnamed thread with number 9, and when I suspend that thread no functionality in the app is lost. So logic tells me that there's some unnecessary CPU usage there.

But I have no clue what is happening in Unnamed Thread 9. I put

```
NSLog(@"thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
```

here and there but Thread 9 did not show up yet, in fact, only thread 1 (The Main Thread) shows up.

How can I figure this out?